# MarshalByRefObject instead of __TransparentProxy

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine

I have C# dll that is working good with .NET Framework application.
That Dll provides WCF client.
Problem is that mentioned client does not work as a part of **Unity** application.

I spent some time trying to understand the problem and here is what I found:
factory's `CreateChannel()` method returns `MarshalByRefObject` instead of __TransparentProxy.

I am using `System.Reflection` to get remote object's properties and invoke them. That approach works perfect for __TransparentProxy. And it does not work at all for `MarshalByRefObject` instance. __TransparentProxy has all the same properties as the remote object. On the other hand `MarshalByRefObject` instance does not have any of these properties.

Is there anything I can do in this situation?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code sample

```
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

        object[] parameters = new object[]
            {
                binding,
                new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1234/ICP01")
            };

        Type factoryType = typeof(ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IICP01Remote));

        ChannelFactory<IICP01Remote> factory = (ChannelFactory<IICP01Remote>)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType, parameters);
        IICP01Remote remote = factory.CreateChannel();

        //remote is MarshalByRefObject not a __TransparentProxy
        float result = remote.GetValue(1);

        factory.Close();
```

Comment: @mjwills - I will try

Comment: Is it not the case that you would simply cast to the type you expect?  Making sure that the type you're casting it to inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`.  (Forgive, but I cba to write a test app)